# Roslyn FileNotFoundException when referencing a nuget package

Tags: roslyn

I have a Roslyn code-gen project with a class that implements `IIncrementalGenerator`.

I have added the following package reference to the generator project

```
<PackageReference Include="Mono.TextTemplating" Version="2.2.1" />
```

But when I build the app I get the following error

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.TextTemplating, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4fa72d50da25cb30' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I have also tried

```
<PackageReference Include="Mono.TextTemplating.Roslyn" Version="2.2.1" />
```

But get the same problem.

How do I consume this package from my code-gen project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of how to include a compile-time dependency without pushing it onto the consuming app.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/CSharpSourceGeneratorSamples.csproj

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Generator dependencies -->
    <PackageReference Include="CsvTextFieldParser" Version="1.2.2-preview" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Handlebars.Net" Version="1.10.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths</GetTargetPathDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGCsvTextFieldParser)\lib\netstandard2.0\CsvTextFieldParser.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGHandlebars_Net)\lib\netstandard2.0\Handlebars.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGNewtonsoft_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really useful - saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

This means that either:

1. Your dependency isn't actually being deployed along with your generator when you build it on disk.
2. You aren't passing the dependencies as analyzers to the compiler along with your generator itself. All files may need to get passed, not just your one that contains the generator itself.

Without details of how you're trying to consume your generator in your project with the error I can't give further hints though.